# If statement goes Crazy

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

Here is the script I'm using to run Index.bat:

```bat
:parsefind
call Index.bat
```

Apparently Index.bat goes crazy and keeps ignoring the "if"s and opens ALL of the directories. I tried setting "tofind" in the batch file instead of Index.bat, but it doesn't seem to change anything. I also tried removing the "(" (didn't fix) and had to put "_" because it would mess up the "or". I made bigger batch files and NEVER encountered this issue before. I also noticed that "(" isn't highlighted in Notepad++ syntax, what's wrong?

```bat
    Set tofind=%cmd:~6%

    if "%tofind%"=="weapons_ability" or "weapons_abilities" (
        start "" "%cd%\unpacked\items\active\weapons\melee\abilities"
    )
    if "%tofind%"=="weapons" or "weps" (
        start "" "%cd%\unpacked\items\active\weapons"
    )
    if "%tofind%"=="melee" or "melee_weapons" (
        start "" "%cd%\unpacked\items\active\weapons\melee"
    )
    if "%tofind%"=="ranged" or "ranged_weapons" (
        start "" "%cd%\unpacked\items\active\weapons\ranged"
    )
    if "%tofind%"=="axe_abilities" or "axe_ability" (
        start "" "%cd%\unpacked\items\active\weapons\melee\abilities\axe"
    )
    if "%tofind%"=="broadsword_abilities" or "broadsword_ability" (
        start "" "%cd%\unpacked\items\active\weapons\melee\abilities\broadsword"
    )
    if "%tofind%"=="generic_abilities" or "generic_ability" (
        start "" "%cd%\unpacked\items\active\weapons\melee\abilities\generic"
    )
    if "%tofind%"=="hammer_abilities" or "hammer_ability" (
        start "" "%cd%\unpacked\items\active\weapons\melee\abilities\hammer"
    )
    if "%tofind%"=="shortsword_abilities" or "shortsword_ability" (
        start "" "%cd%\unpacked\items\active\weapons\melee\abilities\shortsword"
    )
    if "%tofind%"=="spear_abilities" or "spear_ability" (
        start "" "%cd%\unpacked\items\active\weapons\melee\abilities\spear"
    )
    if "%tofind%"=="staff" or "staffs" (
        start "" "%cd%\unpacked\items\active\weapons\staff"
    )
    if "%tofind%"=="staff_abilities" or "staff_ability" (
        start "" "%cd%\unpacked\items\active\weapons\staff\abilities"
    )
    if "%tofind%"=="staff_effectzone" or "staffs_effectzone" (
        start "" "%cd%\unpacked\items\active\weapons\staff\abilities\effectzone"
    )
    if "%tofind%"=="staff_controlprojectile" or "staffs_econtrolprojectile" (
        start "" "%cd%\unpacked\items\active\weapons\staff\abilities\controlprojectile"
    )
    if "%tofind%"=="staff_guidedbolt" or "staffs_guidedbolt" (
        start "" "%cd%\unpacked\items\active\weapons\staff\abilities\guidedbolt"
    )
    if "%tofind%"=="staff_tesla" or "teslastaff" (
        start "" "%cd%\unpacked\items\active\weapons\staff\testlastaff"
    )
    if "%tofind%"=="wand" or "wands" (
        start "" "%cd%\unpacked\items\active\weapons\wand"
    )
    if "%tofind%"=="whip" or "whips" (
        start "" "%cd%\unpacked\items\active\weapons\whip"
    )
    if "%tofind%"=="whip_ability" or "whip abilities" (
        start "" "%cd%\unpacked\items\active\weapons\whip\abilities"
    )
    goto find
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cmd.exe: complex conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772180/cmd-exe-complex-conditions)

Comment: No such thing as OR in batch files.

Comment: @DarkMesa It would be interesting where you have read about `or`. The help displayed on executing `if /?` in a command prompt window does not contain any information about an `or` operator. [IF documentation in MS command line reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754335.aspx) does not mention an operator `or`. And [SS64 documentation for IF command](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) contains also no information about an `or` operator. So it would be really interesting why you thought __IF__ should support an `or` operator in condition.

Comment: @mofi I used "or" in "if" before, and it worked? And now it doesn't exist? I'm rather confused.

Comment: There is no deception here @DarkMesa, there's no such operator!

Comment: @DarkMesa, noting the last line of your snippet, _a closing parenthesis_, suggests to me that the entire snippet posted is within a block. In cases such as these, anything set within that block requires delayed expansion enabling, and the variables referenced using **`!`** instead of **`%`**. I have indented the code in your question to better highlight this.

Comment: I'm assuming that you intend only to open an explorer window with each respective `start` command. As files and directories exclude the use of the back slash character, \, I have removed the unnecessary trailing back slashes from the last but 1 character on lines 7 & 10.

Comment: @DarkMesa no you have never used OR successfully in a Windows batch file.

Comment: @squashman Just tried again to make sure. Yes, it works.

Comment: @squashman here is the script I just tested: if "%CMD:~0,4%"=="menu" or "back" (
goto cmd
) - doesn't matter if I type "menu" or "back", it always goes to "CMD".

Comment: Two points here: 1. There is not `or` operator in `if` command in Batch files. 2. In languages that support the `or` operator you need to _repeat_ the comparison, because "or" by itself is _NOT_ a comparison: `if "%CMD:~0,4%"=="menu" or "%CMD:~0,4%"=="back" ( goto cmd )`

Answer (score 2):

As noted, your `if` syntax is incorrect

```
FOR %%a IN (
"generic_abilities,generic_ability$%cd%\unpacked\items\active\weapons\melee\abilities\generic"
"hammer_abilities,hammer_ability$%cd%\unpacked\items\active\weapons\melee\abilities\hammer"
) DO FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=$" %%w IN (%%a) DO (
 FOR %%i IN (%%w) DO IF /i "%%i"=="%tofind%" ECHO START "" "%%x"
)
```

Here's a way to do the same thing that's easier to maintain.

notes:
There's no real limit on the number of comma-separated option-strings - I used two, but ten is no problem
The `for/f` splits the string `%%a` on `$`, assigning to `%%w` and `%%x`
The `/i` forces a case-insensitive `if`
The resultant `start` command is merely `echo`ed for testing. Remove the `echo` keyword to execute the `start`.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just to show the user that `OR` is not an option with the `IF` command when running a Windows Batch File.

Given the following code.

```
@Echo off
set /P "cmd=enter cmd:"
if "%CMD:~0,4%"=="menu" or "back" ( goto cmd )
echo after if
pause
GOTO :EOF

:cmd
echo In cmd function
pause
GOTO :EOF
```

We will now run the batch file from the cmd prompt and enter menu the first time and back the second time.

```
C:\temp>so.bat
enter cmd:menu
'or' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
after if
Press any key to continue . . .

C:\temp>so.bat
enter cmd:back
after if
Press any key to continue . . .

C:\temp>
```

As you can see in the output, it does not execute the CMD label. The first time the IF command matches the input of menu and then outputs the error that the `OR` command is not a command.  The second time it is run the string comparison is not equal because back does not equal menu.

Comment: It turned out that the "or" statement works one of my Batch files but it doesn't work in new ones. I have no idea why this is happening. I tried to use it once and when I noticed it worked, I used it in other Batch files and I don't recall it failing.

Comment: @DarkMesa, let me know when you find your batch file that works with `IF` and `OR`. I sure would love to see it.

Comment: I do have one that works. I can't explain how, but it does, I am not trying to prove a dead point or anything.

Comment: I have tried to add it in a new batch file and no, it does not work.